# Does GCC have an equivalent to Clang's -Weverything?

Tags: gcc, clang, warnings

I want to be warned about everything possible using the GCC compiler. Is there a way to get the same behaviour as Clang's -Weverything when using GCC?

Answer (score 1):

From the LLVM Clang [Documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#enabling-all-diagnostics):

> Enabling All Diagnostics In addition to the traditional -W flags, one
> can enable all diagnostics by passing -Weverything. This works as
> expected with -Werror, and also includes the warnings from -pedantic.
> Some diagnostics contradict each other, therefore, users of
> -Weverything often disable many diagnostics such as -Wno-c++98-compat and -Wno-c++-compat because they contradict recent C++ standards.
>
> **Since -Weverything enables every diagnostic, we generally don’t
> recommend using it. -Wall -Wextra are a better choice for most
> projects. Using -Weverything means that updating your compiler is more
> difficult because you’re exposed to experimental diagnostics which
> might be of lower quality than the default ones.** If you do use
> -Weverything then we advise that you address all new compiler diagnostics as they get added to Clang, either by fixing everything
> they find or explicitly disabling that diagnostic with its
> corresponding Wno- option.
>
> Note that when combined with -w (which disables all warnings),
> disabling all warnings wins.

From the definition of gcc's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) regarding -Wall argument:

> This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users
> consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to
> prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros. This also
> enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect
> Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options.

Please refer to gcc's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) which flags enabled by -Wall

As a result, it would be frustrating to use the -Weverything with clang because all details will be listed and enabled some experimental warning messages, as mentioned in the quote.

Comment: "-Wall enables all compiler's warning messages" - unfortunately that's incorrect. There're at least `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion`.

Comment: There is `-Wextra`, `-Wnon-gcc`, and many others that aren't enabled. I have a whole list of them. https://gist.github.com/GavinRay97/bae1d93925e55ce0a0084946f24984cf

Comment: To *disable* all warnings: `-w` (says so above but easy to miss, and that's what I came looking for)